# Why is the completion not working? completion issue

Tags: swift, completionhandler

Why is the completion not working ?

After the alert appears, its not transitioning to the other viewController

```
self.present(self.alertController2, animated: true, completion:  {                          
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier:"goToLogin", sender: self)
})
```

Comment: Have you checked the identifier : have you set its ID in Interface Builder ? If so, it must be exactly the same, including lower / uppercase

Comment: But it is not a good idea to have the segue in the completion the way you did it: alert will show but immediately disappear as segue gets triggered.

Comment: i already checked the ID its the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Self.present` using for add this action into view . You need to add this code into your `handler` handler mean `It means what will I do when you click OK`

```
let alertbutton = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .destructive, handler: { 
(UIAlertAction) in
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "your id", sender: self)
        })
```

Complete example :

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Its empty", message: "Going another view", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let alertaction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .destructive, handler: { (UIAlertAction) in
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "your segue id", sender: self)
        })
        alert.addAction(alertaction)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write code first move into new view code run then show alert in main thread for displaying alert.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
//                    AlertView.showAlert(title: Messages.Network.title, message: Messages.Network.message)
//                }
```